# Read data from cloud firestore with firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm an Android developer and recently I've started working on a project based on firebase cloud functions and firestore database. I'm writing an HTTP trigger function that will take two parameters and compare that parameter value with the firestore data value and if the value matches then return a response of true or else false.

**Duplicate Question:**

Yes, there are some question already asked related to mine but they are not similar:

1. [Firestore + cloud functions: How to read from another document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522205/firestore-cloud-functions-how-to-read-from-another-document)
2. [Firebase HTTP Cloud Functions - Read database once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913139/firebase-http-cloud-functions-read-database-once)

**Firebase Docs says**:

> Cloud Firestore supports create, update, delete, and write events

I want to read firestore value from HTTP trigger.

**What I have tried:**

```
exports.userData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

 const user = req.query.user;
 const pass = req.query.pass;
});
```

I'm pretty much stuck at this part. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

P.S. I have very limited knowledge related to JS/TypeScript/NodeJS

Comment: You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to read and write data in Firestore.  There are lots of [samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) too.  I'm afraid to say that you will have to put a lot of effort into learning new things and studying others' code in order to begin to make things work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DougStevenson

Comment: Did you figure this out? @AbhinandanChakraborty

Comment: @Mans No, I stopped using firebase for this project. I learned Node.JS and now I'm developing backend entirely with Node.JS. It's actually pretty easy to do stuff with node and with full control over the backend server

Answer (score 79, accepted):

a bit late, but for any one else stumbling upon this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.someMethod = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var stuff = [];
    var db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection("Users").doc("7vFjDJ63DmhcQiEHwl0M7hfL3Kt1").collection("blabla").get().then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var newelement = {
                "id": doc.id,
                "xxxx": doc.data().xxx,
                "yyy": doc.data().yyy
            }
            stuff = stuff.concat(newelement);
        });
        res.send(stuff)
        return "";
    }).catch(reason => {
        res.send(reason)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you - very helpful to some I'm sure! :)

Comment: it may ask for a dictionary so in res.send -> make it a dictionary `response.send({"result": stuff })`

Comment: How can i get a data i returned on the method on index.js? i need to do that on my TS file, thanks

Comment: @Ruan: is Firestore + Cloud functions stable enough? I'm thinking about integrating this into my project but I'm not sure about the stability of this solution

Comment: @HoangTrinh Yea they pretty stable. BUT if you are looking for 100% stable, than maybe look else where. You do still get the breaking update here or there. Like this one that pissed me off pretty badly a month ago https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1057

Comment: @HumoyunAhmad I've had weird cases where code still executed after res.send

Comment: @Ruan really, can you please specify this. After `send` is called, cloud function container should be terminated according to docs I read (in http triggers only, not background triggers in which you have to return a promise)

Comment: @HoangTrinh Its pretty stable. There are of course various other ways to improve your response messages and error handling to make it even better.

Comment: Hey this to read data from firestore and then return it. Can you help me with how to send data with HTTP call and then write that data to friestore?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [Ruan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516133/2162226), here's an example for `onCall(..)` variation:

```
exports.fireGetColors = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var colors = {};

        var db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection('colors')
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {

              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  var key = doc.id;
                  var color = doc.data();
                  color['key'] = key;

                  colors[key] = color;
              });

              var colorsStr = JSON.stringify(colors, null, '\t');
              console.log('colors callback result : ' + colorsStr);

              resolve(colors);
          })
          .catch(reason => {
              console.log('db.collection("colors").get gets err, reason: ' + reason);
              reject(reason);
          });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, I am trying to do this thing in "Modular" way as what firebase has for version >= 9. Using typescript too as an addition :). Thanks to [Ruan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713519/ruan) for the inspiration.

So, here is how I made it ( similar to the following ):

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
initializeApp();


export const someMethod = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let stuff: any[] = [];
    let db = getFirestore();
    db.collection("Users").doc("7vFjDJ63DmhcQiEHwl0M7hfL3Kt1").collection("blabla").get().then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var newelement = {
                "id": doc.id,
                "xxxx": doc.data().xxx,
                "yyy": doc.data().yyy
            }
            stuff = stuff.concat(newelement);
        });
        res.send(stuff)
        return "";
    }).catch(reason => {
        res.send(reason)
    })
});
```